# Build sources with shelveset and changset

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, msbuild, msbuild-task

I'm using TFS 2010 and Visual Studio 2013. When I queue build I can select option "Latest sources with shelveset" and select shelveset and it is working ok. [image: Queue build screenshot]

I can also set given version on Parameters tab as MSBuild Arguments for eg. by changeset CXXXXXX and it's working ok too.
I'm trying to combine these two options and it's not working. Changes from shelveset are not downloaded during Get task. How can I combine these two options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is impossible for you to combine these two options.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible.Why would you like to combine these two options?

Queue a build through shelveset is a **private build**. The other way you achieved is public build. More info from Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181722(v=vs.120).aspx

If you want to build a shelveset with "specific changeset" , you can roll back  a changeset and put what you want to build in a shelveset. At last ,build the shelveset.

Comment: Why? Because i want to build some version of code with some changes. Or in other words build latest version without some changsets. Did you test your idea about rollback on shelveset? It is simply not working. Edits with rollback tag are ignored for some reason.